# AnyLogic: Efficiently exporting data from experiment with replications

Tags: anylogic

I am doing a parameter variation experiment with 1000 replications for each iteration. For each of these model runs, I want to store a copy of a dataset that is in Main. My current setup is that I am writing that dataset to an excelfile after each simulation run, using the `After simulation run` field in the experiment with the following code:

```
ds_export.fillFrom(root.ds_costAll);
excelfile.writeDataSet(ds_export, 1, 2, 1 + i*2);
```

Where i is a counter for the current iteration.

However, I am running in some performance issues. I believe copies of `ds_costAll` are being stored in my  system's memory, in anticipation of my experiment being completed, upon which it will be written to the excelfile. This means that my system's memory utilization is nearing 100% while the cpu is hardly even bothered. My system has 16gb of memory, and the maximum available memory of the experiment is also 16gb Is there a way to more efficiently export this data?

Answer (score 0):

How many cores are you using in runtime?
Tools->Preferences->Runtime->Number of processes for parallel execution

Might be an option to reduce it a bit.

Comment: It has access to all my processor cores. In any case, I don't believe the CPU is the culprit for the poor performance. The memory is being filled by keeping datasets in memory before writing the excel file, once the experiment has finished.

Comment: right, but every core is using certain memory. Decreasing # of cores decreases overall memory usage.

Comment: Another trick to try - 1) uncheck the "Load on model startup" and "save on model termination" flags in your excelFile. 2) add two lines of code to your After simulation fuction: excelfile.readFile() (this should precede everything). and excelfile.writeFile() (this should be the last line). Alternatively you can try do it in other places - e.g. "before each experiment"(readFile) and After iteration (writeFile).